# PHP: show only last data from same data on loop

Tags: php, loops

i have data from php loop foreach like this

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    echo $row->name;
}
```

[image: loop result]

how to make the result show only the end data without remove others if data has same (if data have same value, hide all except the last one) like this:

[image: hope loop result]

*sorry bad english, this is the first time i ask here. thank you

Comment: given the limited example, i'd suggest filtering them with [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) otherwise you need to compare what the last value was, or if that value has been echoed before.

Comment: Do you want highest index of any element or just want to make unique ?

Comment: please show you mysql fetch code.

Comment: can you give me the example code

Comment: this code just example to make question easier

Comment: @ErwinHeldyG, Check out my answer and the demo example: [https://3v4l.org/ZRenf](https://3v4l.org/ZRenf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data_seek method might help. This assumes your array is reasonable ordered to begin with.

```
$rowCount = 0;
$res = $query->result();
foreach($res as $row) {
    if ($rowCount < $res->num_rows - 1) {
        // set internal pointer to next row
        $res->data_seek($rowCount + 1);
        // if the row names match, print an empty string
        // otherwise print the current name
        $nextRow = $res->fetch_row();
        if ($row->name == $nextRow->name) {
            echo "";
            // reset the internal pointer
            $res->data_seek($rowCount);
        } else {
            echo $row->name;
        }
     } else {
         echo $row->name;
     }
    // update the row count
    $rowCount += 1;
}
```

Comment: thank you, data_seek help me, i can use next_row to codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

[Online Check](https://3v4l.org/ZRenf), This is just a demo example.

See below the real example:

At first you need to use `array_search` for get the position of the same data, if exist then just remove it using `$arr[$pos] = '';`, and each and every time you need to import data into the new array called `$arr` and after completing fetching data you need to use a foreach loop to print them.

```
$arr = array();
foreach($query->result() as $row){
    $pos = array_search($row->name, $arr);
    if($pos !== false)
        $arr[$pos] = '';
    $arr[] = $row->name;    
}

foreach($arr as $val){
    echo $val.'<br/>';
}
```

Check this and let me know.

Comment: by overwriting the value the blanks will be above the letters, not below as in the `image` in the example it would be as if there were 3 B's not 3 C's

Comment: downvote, I think i do that's why you do. can you explain please?

Comment: When you change the value using the `pos` you push the non-empty item down.  Because that pos becomes blank and you add the value to the end of the array.

Comment: Lol, my mistake, be nice... That's a bit hostile of a tone there.  Little hard over a laggy VPN connection,

Comment: Still gonna be issues if the order is not guaranteed, just saying.